# plain javascript, onclick not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

Now I am not a star really with Javascript, but i seem to encounter the all known problem with mobile devices and the onclick function. Onclick requires a mouse action where off course on the phone that doesnt apply. Now in Jquery, you can use "on" .. but how does this work with regular javascript?

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('reserveer-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("reserveer-knop");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    if (x > 768) {

        //event.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the touchstart event, as per MDN docs "The touchstart event is fired when a touch point is placed on the touch surface." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart - The usage is, for example, `el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `onclick` to `addEventListener` and see if that helps you..

```js
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    if (x > 768) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can also pass named function to `addEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

Binding the click event listener to the element should fix the problem you've been having.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    if (x > 768) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could try using the touchstart event, which works just like the "mousedown" event, just for mobile.

```
elem.addEventListener("touchstart", handler);
```

Your code would look like this:

```
btn.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    if (x > 768) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: He should listen to `click` instead of `touchstart`.  Handling `touchstart` would would affect dragging actions, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, after setting z-index to 100 it worked.
Seems like in my case there was a z-index issue.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any `async/await` functions in your code or any arrow functions `() => {}`. Mobile browsers seem to use older versions of JavaScript before async/await or arrow function were introduced.